# Yii2 + htaccess + wamp gives 404 Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, wamp, virtualhost

Please help, I've read a lot of posts about this issue, nothing helps.

I have yii2 installation under: c:/sites/mysite

The index.php file is in: c:/sites/mysite/web

I have htaccess file under c:/sites/mysite that looks like this:

    # turn on rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html?$ home.php [NC,R,L]
DirectoryIndex home.php

```
# on what should it skip the rules
RewriteRule ^(favicon.ico) - [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Do not allow calls from servers testing ou server fi were a proxy
#  http://serverfault.com/questions/499125/banning-all-azenv-php-request-to-my-server
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*/azenv\.php [NC,OR]
#RewriteRule .* - [F]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I have my-vhosts file that has this code:

    ServerName armanager
    ServerAlias armanager
    DocumentRoot "c:/sites/armanager/web"
    
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted

Going to mysite on firefox works fine.

I have a controller esController with actionSettings function.
I have a view settings.php

Going to mysite/es/settings gives me the dreaded 404 Not Found error.

Can you please help?

Comment: Virtual hosts code wasn't copied correctly:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName armanager
    ServerAlias armanager
    DocumentRoot "c:/sites/armanager/web"
    <directory "c:/sites/armanager/web">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I added this *.htaccess* in the web folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now, everything works.